# Show top X% for specific tags in user profile?

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page, top-users

Would it be possible to display a link similar to the "Top X% this quarter" link on the user profile page for specific tags? Something like "Top X% in [c#] this month".

It would make it easier to show which tags a user has been actively and effectively participating in recently instead of just all time (by looking at their individual tag upvotes).